# rack cache with X-Rack-Cache:miss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I setup rack cache with redis

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true
```

And it works but sometimes (way to often), caching doesn't work as expected. Event though cache headers are properly set `Cache-Control:max-age=20, public, s-maxage=600` I see that response headers contain `X-Rack-Cache:miss` which means that URL was not in cache and it also didn't store the server response into cache store.

URL is like this (has 1 GET param for language):

```
http://localhost:3000/js/JAYy-euKaergqRsTlrn67w/events.js?lng=es
```

and if I add extra params or change the `lng` param to eg 'de' it than stores the response as expected. It seems like it acts a bit randomly.

I noticed this only on development environment - on production i seems like it always work as expected. What could be the reason?